# Radgrid missing fields when exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

my.ascx >>

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="ajaxPanel_Header" runat="server">
  <asp:Button ID="Button_ExportToExcel" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="ExportToExcel" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClick="Button_ExportToExcel_Click" />
   <telerik:RadGrid ID="grid_Permission" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="200" GridLines="None" CellSpacing="0" AllowSorting="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" ShowFooter="True" OnNeedDataSource="grid_Permission_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="grid_Permission_ItemDataBound" OnDetailTableDataBind="grid_Permission_DetailTableDataBind" OnItemCommand="grid_Permission_ItemCommand">
      ...
      ...
      ...
      <MasterTableView CellSpacing="-1" NoMasterRecordsText="Kayıt bulunamadı." DataKeyNames="MrkDocHeaderId,ProdStoreOrderDetailId,IsStoreOutSubscribed,ProdStoreStockTypeId" HierarchyLoadMode="ServerOnDemand" Name="tbl_Master" EnableHeaderContextMenu="True" GroupLoadMode="Client" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10">     
         ...
         ...                                               
         <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Onay Durumu" DataField="IsStoreOutSubscribedText" FilterControlAltText="Filter IsStoreOutSubscribedText column" UniqueName="IsStoreOutSubscribedText" Visible="False" Exportable="true">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
               <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
         </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      </MasterTableView>
   </telerik:RadGrid>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

my.ascx.cs >>

```
protected void Button_ExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //RadGrid grid = grid_Permission;
    if (grid_Permission != null)
    {
        if (grid_Permission.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                //grid_Permission.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = GridExcelExportFormat.Biff;
                grid_Permission.ExportSettings.FileName = string.Format("MamulDepoUrunRaporu_{0}", DateTime.Now);
                grid_Permission.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
                grid_Permission.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
                grid_Permission.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
                grid_Permission.MasterTableView.UseAllDataFields = true;
                //grid_Permission.MasterTableView.GetColumn("img_IsStoreOutSubscribed").Visible = false;
                grid_Permission.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();

            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my question:

I have a telerik radgrid. I want to export to excel some fields of this grid, visible or not.
But in my exported file i cannot see the **visible=false** field values even they are marked **Exportable="true"**

I tried to change column visibilty to true before the export and set false again etc. nothing is changed.

Any ideas about the reason?

Comment: try calling the grid's Rebind() method before exporting in case some change needs a rebind to get the data again

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow with the answer below and return the result. I am not on my IDE now. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Have you tested the solution I suggested? Is it working?

Comment: @rdmptn i am not sure why but Rebind() solves my problem . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the origin of your problem, however this is how I do export to excel and it works.

```
 protected void ExpExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //exclude columns from being exported in excel
        foreach (GridColumn col in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns)
        {
            if ((col.UniqueName.Contains("EditCommandColumn")) ||
                (col.UniqueName.Contains("column1")))
            {
                col.Display = false;
            }
            else
            {
                col.Display = true;
            }
        }
        //format content to be exported in excel
        foreach (GridFilteringItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.FilteringItem))

        item.Visible = false;
       //the other settings you need...
        RadGrid1.ExportSettings.FileName = "yourFileName;
        RadGrid1.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
        RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = Telerik.Web.UI.GridExcelExportFormat.ExcelML;
       //example of renaming column header in excel            
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("something").HeaderText = "something else";
        //finally export the columns
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
    }
```

Let us know if this is of help.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow and return the result. I am not on my IDE now. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I tried and find the solution at @rdmptn's comment. Thanks for your help.